# What does bianniu 变牛 mean?

Tags: meaning

I have seen this expression in a few texts, including news articles, but it does not seem to be commonly used.

Here are a few examples of context:

"...第二舰队变牛了以后调到了第二舰队当先任参谋..."

"高考报志愿：盘点改名后变牛的10所大学"

"为什么很多人说读《毛泽东选集》就变牛了"

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide context.

Comment: Thx. I've added context to the question.

Answer (score 2):

> "...第二舰队变牛了以后调到了第二舰队当先任参谋..."

To me this sentence seems a little bit strange. I guess there is a name of the person before this sentence.

If so, then the sentence means that: After the second fleet becomes stronger, someone was transferred and become the chief of staff there.

> "改名后变牛的10所大学"

Translation: 10 College became elite school after changing their names.

> "为什么很多人说读《毛泽东选集》就变牛了"

Translation: Why many people say that you will become smarter/sharper after reading "Selected Works of Mao Zedong"?

So you can see that in these sentences, “变牛” means becomes stronger. The exact meaning might change according to the specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

Without context, I would guess that this probably means "to become more awesome".

"牛" has a slang meaning of "awesome". "变" here probably means "to become more [...]".

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what it means. 牛 is actually short for 牛屄 (牛逼), which means awesome. Media just writes 牛, since the word is rather vulgar. Typical usage: 最牛钉子户, referring to those odd houses that resist modernization.

Answer (score 0):

牛 is Internet slang. It means awesome.

I am not sure but I heard it because cows (The real meaning of 牛 is cows or ox.) are hard-working and strong so in China they use 牛 to call someone or something awesome.

I said China because it is only used in China. In Taiwan, they don't know it (I am not sure about Singapore, Hong Kong, Macao, ...etc. But I guess they do not understand either).

Answer (score 0):

牛 ＝ 牛B ＝ 牛B哄哄

It's not a good word, but widely used to represent "good, awesome, terrific" with some negative denotation sometimes.

Gradually, the negative meaning has diminished. 牛 = fucking awesome, hot.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, we use the word to express that one wants to become more capable